# Load data from file into an array

Tags: c++

Been stuck on this for a while, I have a .dat file with 16 rows and 3 columns.

ex: Andrew 9  12

I need to store the name of the player, the players number, and the points scored as shown above.

C++ btw.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have so far? If it is `c++`, why the `c#` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// include fstream and string

Your regular ifstream will serve you well.

```
string playerName;
int playerScore;
int playerPoints;

openedInFile>>playerName>>playerScore>>playerPoints;
// loop for next row
```

Store as appropriate.